# How to write rspec for tagged logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

````
logger.tagged(mail.message_id) do
      logger.info({ to: Array(mail.to).join(', '),
        from: mail.from,
        subject: mail.subject,
        time: Time.zone.now,
        headers: mail.header,
        errors: mail.errors,
        delivery_status_part: mail.delivery_status_part,
        message_id: mail.message_id })``` 




 expect(Rails.logger).to have_received(:info).with({ to: Array(mail.to).join(', '),
        from: mail.from,
        subject: mail.subject,
        time: Time.zone.now,
        headers: mail.header,
        errors: mail.errors,
        delivery_status_part: mail.delivery_status_part,
        message_id: mail.message_id })
````

I need to assert if loggers info has received the object, while asserting the error expected to have received info, but that method has been mocked instead of stubbed or spied.

Comment: You don't say if this provided code is working, or if not, what you have tried to do to debug it. Please give us as much detail as you can, like where in your application is this code being executed.